# STT(speech to text) ESPNET recipe modeling stage 3 error

Tags: artificial-intelligence, speech-to-text

I'm trying to form a STT model from using codes and models from espnet github.
my dataset is all set and planning to start modeling from stage 3 using 4 gpus but the errors are coming out.

2024-01-15T19:36:11 (format_wav_scp.sh:110:main) [info]: without segments
run.pl: 32 / 32 failed, log is in dump/raw/org/train/logs/format_wav_scp.*.log

so i ran cat log is in dump/raw/org/train/logs/format_wav_scp.1.log
and this comes out

~/yhc2/espnet/egs2/aihub_kuniv/asr1$ cat dump/raw/org/train/logs/format_wav_scp.1.log

## pyscripts/audio/format_wav_scp.py --fs 16k --audio-format flac dump/raw/org/train/logs/wav.1.scp dump/raw/org/train/data/format.1

## Started at Mon Jan 15 19:36:11 KST 2024

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pyscripts/audio/format_wav_scp.py", line 14, in 
from typeguard import check_argument_types
ImportError: cannot import name 'check_argument_types' from 'typeguard' (/home/bootcamp/yhc2/espnet/tools/anaconda/envs/espnet/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typeguard/**init**.py)

## Accounting: time=1 threads=1

## Ended (code 1) at Mon Jan 15 19:36:12 KST 2024, elapsed time 1 second

i tried to solve it by following steps
source.path.sh
python3.9 -m pip list | grep typeguard
python3.9 -m pip install typeguard==2.13.3
conda deactivate
run bash run.sh --stage 3 --ngpu 4,

But i'm getting the same problem. i tried reinstalling typeguard but won't work.
Any suggestions?